# How to put your photoshop design into your windows 8 app?

Tags: user-interface, windows-8

can someone explain to me, or point out some nice articles, how I can use my photoshop design and correctly implement it into my app ? I want to use Xaml/VB for the application. I have made a nice game design which I want to use but I don't quiet understand how I can use this design into my xaml app. The borders should always be on the border of the screen.

image sample: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/215154

kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134795(v=expression.40).aspx) about "Import an Adobe Photoshop file" may be helpful. 
Or, if a detour is acceptable, there is [another one here](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/) for converting Adobe Illustrator to export WPF and Silverlight compatible XAML. 
Since only the converted XAML files are desired, it doesn't matter whether the project is a WPF project or a Windows 8 project.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use Blend, which has an "import from Photoshop" option.

1. First, download Blend.  Although it installs with the free version of Visual
   Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8, which is [here](http://aka.ms/JenVS2012) halfway down the page in blue, the importer isn't supported in that version.  You can either use Expression Blend 4 or [Expression Blend for Silverlight 5 preview](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9503) to import your Photoshop image and then copy over the resulting canvas to Blend for Visual Studio 2012.
2. Then, open Blend.  Cancel all of the wizards, or create a project but then close it.  Then, under the File menu, you should see an "Import" option which will allow you to import an Adobe Photoshop file.

Comment: hey Jennifer thanks. But then what ? I already looked into it and you can indeed import the file (without layer styles appearently) but what should I do then ? Do I have to make a grid of some sort ?

Comment: Here is a tutorial on creating your first Windows 8 app in XAML: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974581.aspx.  It outlines the basics of Windows 8 development.

Comment: Thank you for the link Jennifer but I cannot find the answer to my question in the tut you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Before I give my answer, there is one thing to note : MS design guidelines suggest you should steer clear of adding your own chrome to an app - the design philosophy is such that you shouldn't need to do it.

That said, you can accomplish this by slicing your image into 8 parts, and having an overlaying grid in your app XAML.  This is similar to the way you might want to lay out the same thing in HTML.

```
<!-- content for the game here -->
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Height="30" Width="30" Source="TopLeftSlice.png" />
    <Image Height="30" Grid.Column="1" Source="TopMiddleSlice.png" />
    <Image Height="30" Width="30" Grid.Column="2" Source="TopRightSlice.png" />
    <Image Width="30" Grid.Row="1" Source="MiddleLeftSlice.png" />
    <Image Width="30" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Source="MiddleRightSlice.png" />
    <Image Height="30" Width="30" Grid.Row="2" Source="BottomLeftSlice.png" />
    <Image Height="30" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Source="BottomMiddleSlice.png" />
    <Image Height="30" Width="30" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Source="BottomRightSlice.png" />
</Grid>
```

You'll need to mess around with the width, height and stretch properties on your images to get them to look right, but as long as this is defined appropriately on your page, it should appear as an overlay and your previously defined content should show through the gap / transparencies.